# How to verify Grails 2.1.0 Hibernate L2 Cache?

Tags: hibernate, grails, ehcache

I am using Grails 2.1.0. I have been trying to verify/profile my L2 cache. Now, I doubt that hibernate/cache settings are correct.

#### **•  I have enabled generate_statistics in the hibernate settings located in conf\DataSource.grooy.**

```
hibernate {
    generate_statistics = true
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
    format_sql = true
    use_sql_comments = true
}
```

#### **•  I have enabled the cache in the domain mapping.**

```
package com.att.failbox.log.cause
class LogCauseMemento {
    Date dateCreated
    static mapping = {
        version false
        id generator: 'assigned'
        table 'log_cause'
        cache: true
    }
}
```

#### **•  I have added the corresponding entry the domain entry in ehcache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" >
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
<cacheManagerEventListenerFactory class="" properties=""/>
<defaultCache
    eternal="false"
    timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    diskPersistent="false"
    />
<cache name="com.att.failbox.log.cause.LogCauseMemento"
    maxElementsInMemory="100000"
    eternal="true"
    />
</ehcache>
```

#### **•  However, when I try to verfu the L2 cache using “stats.getSecondLevelCacheRegionNames()” I am only getting “StandardQueryCache, UpdateTimestampsCache”.**

```
import org.hibernate.stat.Statistics
class DomainProfilerService {
    def sessionFactory
    def displayStatistics() {
        Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics()
        def names = stats.getSecondLevelCacheRegionNames()
        names.each(){ println it }
    }
}
```

### **Am I looking into the correct place to verify my L2 cache?**

Comment: @Joel 
Thanks Joel, you are correct.  the colon was the problem.  I also think that using Groovy 1.8 with Grails 2.1.0 might contributed to the problem as well. 

thanks again, 

Sami